# How to stretch 6 <li> tags till the end of the line?

Tags: html, css, navbar, responsive

I have 6 list item tags displayed horizontally in my navigation menu. I want to stretch these 6 `<li>` tags till the end of the line but the problem is that I don't know the length of the `<li>` tags (because text in `<li>` tag can be changed) and this navbar should be responsive.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use flexbox. In your case:

```
ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  
  padding: 10px;
  background: gray;
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Новости</li>
  <li>Новости</li>
  <li>Новости</li>
  <li>Новости</li>
  <li>Новости</li>
  <li>Новости</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try a flexbox, like the example below.

```css
ul{
 display: flex;
 width: 100%;
 justify-content: space-around;
 list-style: none;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<ul>
<li>first</li>
<li>second</li>
<li>third</li>
<li>fourth</li>
</ul>
```